# Most appropriate representation of 3,4,4,5-tetramethylheptane

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is there a specific correct way to draw the structure of 3,4,4,5-tetramethylheptane?

[image: structure image]

Comment: You might want to have a look at [*Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams* (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277).

Comment: but what is the short answer?

Comment: The second way is somewhat better. Also, all your angles in the main chain are way too acute.

Comment: Neither of the two is good. If don't know the actual angles, just go with more symbolic and less misleading representation.

Comment: @Mithoron its a rough sketch the main importance of the diagram is for the 4,4 methyl placement and nothing to do with the actual angles.

Comment: @reset You are asking about the structure, which *is* a set of both angles and distances. As Mithoron rightfully suggested, *both* do matter a lot. There are recommended/standardized values, values that tolerably represent a projection of a complex 3D object onto a 2D layer with justified adjustments, and there are incorrect ones. Given it's a trivial case and there is no objective reason to use visually incoherent bonds and odd angles, your structures are both falling into the last category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, it cannot be said that a specific representation is “right” and that all others are “wrong”. Nevertheless, the relevant guidelines given in the [*Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams* (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277) read as follows:

> *GR-4.1.3 Atoms with four bonds drawn*
> Atoms with four bonds may be depicted in several different ways, with a preference among these ways determined by context.
> When two of the adjacent atoms are each connected to no additional atoms and two of the adjacent atoms are each connected to at least one additional atom, the four bonds should be separated by one 60° angle, an opposing 120° angle, and two 90° angles. Because of the 120° angle, this style will not disrupt the orientation of a chain in which it appears. (…)

Therefore, the structure diagram of 3,4,4,5-tetramethylheptane should look like this:

[image: 3,4,4,5-tetramethylheptane]

Note the 120° angles of the chain, which are missing in the examples given in the question.